# How to unmarshal a pointer to an array that should later be freed?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling

I want to invoke the [AuditEnumerateCategories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375636(v=vs.85).aspx) function from a C# program, for which I am declaring the external function like this:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool AuditEnumerateCategories(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)] out Guid[] auditCategories,
    out uint numCategories);
```

And then I can use it in my code as:

```
if (AuditEnumerateCategories(out Guid[] categories, out uint dummySize)) 
{
    ...
}
```

This works fine, but then I noticed the following in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375636(v=vs.85).aspx) regarding the array that is returned as the first argument:

> When you have finished using this buffer, free it by calling the AuditFree function.

Is there a way of getting an `IntPtr` out of that `categories` variable that I can use to invoke the [`AuditFree`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375654(v=vs.85).aspx) function? Or should I declare `AuditEnumerateCategories` as returning an `IntPtr` and do the marshalling to `Guid[]` myself?

Comment: You have to do the thing you don't want to do but know you have to do :)

Comment: Haha, it's exactly like that :) Was hoping there was a magical `MarshalAndThenFree(AuditFree)` annotation  I was not aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The framework won't do this automatically for you. You'll need to declare the parameter as an IntPtr and do all the marshaling manually.

Comment: Won't the .NET even try to free the memory with `CoTaskMemFree` (so the wrong deallocator)? It isn't always clear the [sentence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-behavior) *The interop marshaler always attempts to free memory allocated by unmanaged code. This behavior complies with COM memory management rules, but differs from the rules that govern native C++.* on what is applied...

Comment: @xanatos but that's not AuditFree

Comment: My point was that it was adding a problem (memory leak) to another problem (trying to use the wrong deallocator on a block of memory. Some deallocators can cause crashes when used on the wrong block of memory)

Comment: CoTaskMemFree() is no longer special since Win8.  Does the same thing that LocalFree() does, releasing the allocation from the default process heap.  Very nasty trap, it is too likely to actually work when AuditFree() is required.  But not on Win7.  Let's not tell the OP :)